# Is it possible to use MapKit data without using Apple's map?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I want to make a nearby stores app kind of like Yelp but with a unique twist. Since I'm starting on iOS an API like MapKit seems like it would be a good way to get location and other data about nearby businesses. However, I don't want to display a map, I just need precise location data and information about the business. Is there a way to do this with MapKit or should I seek another API?

Comment: You don't have to display a map to use MapKit or use Lication Services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [MKLocalSearch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch)
but I didn't use it as Apple Maps not that powerful in places that my app will be promoted.

also you can use [Foursquare](https://web.archive.org/web/20221024034716/https://developer.foursquare.com/) API, pretty much sweet API I used it for my tutorials.

Good luck, if you have any further question just ping me.